# running bash shell code in IPython notebook

Tags: python, bash, ipython-magic

I am trying to run a code in jupyter notebook Python3 see below:

```
%% bash
rm rvd2.txt
rm rvd22.txt
 rm lsfdout.lsf

    cat wrench.txt | sed 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | 
 sed 's/[ \t]*$//' | \
 sed '/^$/d'| tr -cd '[:alnum:] [:space:]' >> rvd2.txt

 awk 'length>3'  < rvd2.txt > rvd22.txt

 cat rvd22.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 250 > lsfdout.lsf
```

The error I get is this,

```
 File "<ipython-input-33-7c6457f6d2eb>", line 2
  %% bash
   ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am totally out of clue why this happens, as a multiline code is supposed to be using double percent sign before bash

Comment: You shouldn't have a space between `%%` and `bash`

Comment: I tried this suggestion as well, same error reported with only difference `%%bash` as the stated error.

Comment: I have reached one stage of correction by removing the `%%bash` and putting `!` mark at beginning of each bash code as follows,
    `!rm rvd2.txt
    !rm rvd22.txt
!rm lsfdout.lsf

!cat wrench.txt | sed 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/[ \t]*$//' | \
sed '/^$/d'| tr -cd '[:alnum:] [:space:]' >> rvd2.txt

!awk 'length>3'  < rvd2.txt > rvd22.txt

!cat rvd22.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 250 > lsfdout.lsf`

Comment: But the above code gives the following error.  `sort: write failed: 'standard output': Broken pipe
sort: write error` how to resolve this.

Comment: I am able to run the script successfully but this code line needs improvement `!cat rvd22.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 250 > lsfdout.lsf` as even though the file created is ok, but can this code be improved to remove the error produced everytime.